# Kobuki 12V 1.5A connector?

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this page](http://kobuki.yujinrobot.com/wiki/connectors/) describing the Kobuki power connectors, the 12V 1.5A connector is similar to [Molex PN : 5566-02B2](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=Molex%205566-02B2).  The connector on the robot is single-row 1-circuit but all I can find is a two-row version.  Is it possible there is a different Molex part number that matches?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236432/kobuki-12v-1.5a-connector?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-08**:
The connectors you link to are a two-pin Mini-Fit (2 rows, 1 column). I'm reasonably certain that's the connector that's on the Kobuki

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thanks Austin.  I got myself confused with the [PN on the Molex site](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0039299022_PCB_HEADERS.xml) that shows only two-row connectors.  However, it's still not clear to me which mating connector I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This *looks* like the correct mating connector, but I haven't bought one to verify it: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/curtis-industries/BLP-SC000002/364-1197-ND/3877174

Molex makes many versions of the mating connector and crimp pins, with variations in temperature resistance, corrosion resistance, material and cost. These can usually be found through the "Mating Product" and "Associated Product" sections on the part page on DigiKey.

The company where I work has a Molex Mini-Fit crimper ($300+), so I borrow that when I need to make cables, but it doesn't scale well for hobbyists. If you have access to one, this housing should be reasonable: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0039012020/WM3700-ND/61315 . Depending on your wire size you can go from that to individual crimp pins.

If you buy crimp pins for hand crimping, **CHOOSE BULK PACKAGING**, not tape. Bulk connectors come pre-separated, tape connectors come attached to a metal tape and need to be cut off before you can use them in the hand crimper.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-08**:
Many thanks Austin! I really appreciate the time you took to find that part.  I have ordered one from DigiKey and will report back here if it works.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-10**:
I just received [the connector](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/curtis-industries/BLP-SC000002/364-1197-ND/3877174) listed above and unfortunately it does not fit the 12V 1.5A jack.  It *does* fit the 12V 5A jack.  Sure would be nice if Yujin Robot could post links or sell the connectors...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-11**:
I went from the part number you linked and didn't read the Yujin page carefully; they do clearly state that the 5566-02B2 (mini-fit) is for the 12V@5A connector.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-11**:
I don't see a similar pre-assmebled cable for the 43045-0224 (micro-fit). DigiKey does sell the housings: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0430250200/WM1783-ND/252496 and crimp pins; but the crimper is still about the same price :(

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-11**:
Thanks again Austin.  That micro-fit connector looks right so I've ordered one from DigiKey and some crimp pins.  I have a cheap crimp tool that I've used before so hopefully that will get the job done.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-16**:
Yep, that's the one.  Just received it from DigiKey and it fits the 12V 1.5A jack.  It is DigiKey part number WM1783-ND and manufacturer (Molex) part number 0430250200.

**Comment by [danie11am](https://answers.ros.org/users/30203/danie11am/) on 2019-11-23**:
Follow-up question - so I'm attempting the same task of getting power out of the 12V 1.5A socket in Kobuki.

I understand that I need to order this "housing connector" (DigiKey part number WM1783-ND https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0430250200/WM1783-ND/252496). However I'm a newbie in electronics. May I ask what I need to do next, so that it connects with a power cable where the other end is a standard DC male plug?

I understand I need the "crimp pins" and a "crimp tool", but I don't know exactly what to do and don't know how to connect it with a DC male plug.. Please help!

I'm trying to power a small external LCD screen like https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/New-7-inch-HD-HDMI-LCD-Display-Screen-Monitor-VGA-HDMI-AV-Audio-Black-/143404057545

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-11-24**:
Instead of buying crimp pins and a crimper, you can also buy pre-crimped wires with the micro-fit crimp pins from digikey: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0430300001-12-B0/0430300001-12-B0-ND/5962941 . Digikey sells these in a variety of lengths and colors. Then you just stick these in the two-pin housing, and hook the other end up to the DC plug for your screen.

**Comment by [danie11am](https://answers.ros.org/users/30203/danie11am/) on 2019-11-24**:
Thank you @ahendrix!! I see, so I should buy 2 items from your link and stick them to the "housing connector" previously mentioned. And follow-up newbie question - how do I "hook the other end up to the DC plug"? Do I order something like this: https://www.robotgear.com.au/Product.aspx/Details/774-DC-Barrel-Jack-Connector-Male-with-screw-terminals-2-1mm-x-5-5mm or is there more proper way to solder the wire into a plug?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-11-24**:
Yes; you need two of the wires from DigiKey, since the kobuki has a two-pin plug. DC barrel plugs come in many sizes; you need to get the size that fits your display. Pay attention to the inside and outside diameter.
The screw terminal jacks are great for prototypes, but a soldered jack will be more reliable. Many vendors sell a huge variety of DC barrel plugs. DigiKey is my favorite source: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/barrel-power-connectors/435 ; you'll want to filter for "Plug" and "In Stock", and then filter by diameter. If you're not in the US, you can probably find a local vendor with a similar selection.